# How can I save the id of a child record in the parent without calling .save again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a problem where legacy code was calling `.save` inside an `after_save` callback until Rails 5.1, but because of how `saved_change_to_attribute` replaces `attribute_changed?` in `after_` callbacks, it is a problem to call `.save` twice (`.save` affects `.changes`).

I now need to replicate the same behaviour without calling `.save` twice.

In my Rails 5.1.7 app (preparing for 5.2 upgrade):

```
class OtherModel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :my_model, inverse_of: :other_model_history
end

class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :other_model_history, class_name: 'OtherModel', inverse_of: :my_model
  belongs_to :latest_other_model, class_name: 'OtherModel'
  before_create :initialize_first_other_model

  def initialize_first_other_model
    initial_other = OtherModel.new(name: 'initial')
    other_model_history << initial_other
    latest_other_model = initial_other
    # When it finally reaches save (this is before_create) I want ActiveRecord to know
    # to save the ID of initial_other in latest_other_model_id ... but it doesn't
  end
end
```

When `MyModel.new.save` is called, `initialize_other_model` creates the initial `OtherModel` instance with the correct `other_model.my_model_id` based on `my_model.id`.

BUT, the `my_model.latest_other_model_id` is nil. This is despite
`latest_other_model` correctly referencing the `initial_other` object.

How can I tell ActiveRecord that it must set `my_model.latest_other_model_id = initial_other.id`?

EDIT: with `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

```
DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "my_models" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2019-05-31 06:12:27.006455"], ["updated_at", "2019-05-31 06:12:27.006455"]]
DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "other_models" ("my_model_id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["my_model_id", 3], ["name", "initial"], ["created_at", "2019-05-31 06:12:27.015472"], ["updated_at", "2019-05-31 06:12:27.015472"]]
DEBUG -- :    (1.5ms)  commit transaction
```

You can see that MyModel is inserted first, without the `other_model`, then `OtherModel` is inserted with the id from `MyModel`. I want Rails to also know to then insert `my_models.latest_other_model_id`, without calling `.save`

Comment: Isn't it not saving the id as you want bc the record is not saved? what if you `initial_other = OtherModel.create(name: 'initial')` That would then save the record and allow you to set the belongs to relationship. The `my_model_id` is getting set, bc you're saving the my model but not the other

Comment: `OtherModel.create` would require an id from `MyModel` so Rails would instantly save `MyModel` (inside the callback) and wipe out the `changes` that I'm trying to preserve for the sake of `saved_change_to_attribute` in later callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use `update_column` in after_save. This saves the reference from `my_model` to `other_model` without affecting `saved_changes`. My callbacks are now

before_create:

```
  initial_other = OtherModel.new(name: 'initial')
  other_model_history << initial_other
```

after_save:

```
update_column('latest_other_model_id', other_model_history.last.id)
```

Note: I wouldn't recommend this style of initialising inside callbacks to anyone who doesn't have it forced upon them by legacy code. This feels very fragile.